# Programming Macro to restrict some data

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a Excel Macro program for the following conditions

> - A & B two columns of data given on a excel sheet
> - If A gives null value at each time,
> - B should not show his value whether B has a value or not....

Please help me to write this condition

Comment: I'm not sure if a undestood your request. Could you share what have you tried so far and sample data with expected resuts

Comment: -1 because "give me teh codez"

Comment: Have you tried conditional formatting? I think it could be done that way without macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use column **C** and type following formula in cell C1 and copy it down:

```
=if(A1="";"";B1)
```

Then you can hide column **B** and use column **C** instead of **B**